# Grouping 3 tables together while using \resizebox

Tags: tables

I'm trying to group 3 different tables together so they will appear all behind each other and not on different pages.
I've read a few answers here on the forum already, but just don't seem to get the hang of it.....so maybe one of you might help :)

I've tried to put all tabular in one table and put a resizebox in that table, but I continuously get an error.... any help is appreciated :)

```
\begin{table}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2,4cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{12cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Abkürzung} &\textbf{Bezeichnung}  &   \textbf{Beschreibung} &   \textbf{Herkunft}  \\ 
            \hline\hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    }
    \caption{Annahme 2} 
    \label{tab:annahme2} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{12cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Abkürzung} &\textbf{Bezeichnung}  &   \textbf{Beschreibung} &   \textbf{Quelle}  \\ 
            \hline\hline
        \end{tabular} 
    }
    \caption{Annahme 3} 
    \label{tab:annahme3} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.4cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{12cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Abkürzung} &\textbf{Bezeichnung}  &   \textbf{Beschreibung} &   \textbf{Quelle}  \\ 
            \hline\hline 

        \end{tabular} 
    }
    \caption{Annahme 4} 
    \label{tab:annahme4} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: never put a table in a resizebox

Comment: to manke sure all three tables float together just delete the two occurrences of `\end{table}

\begin{table}` so that all three tabular and all three captions are in the same `table`

Comment: oh wow......thats embarrassing.....after 12h of work my brain stopped working apparently :D thanks @David

Comment: to your tables you should add magnifying glass  ... otherwise they are not readable :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can but all the tables in a single `table` so they float together, (only scale tables as a last resort, and even then don't do it:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\centering
X\dotfill X

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Abkürzung} &\textbf{Bezeichnung}  &   \textbf{Beschreibung} &   \textbf{Herkunft}  \\ 
            \hline\hline 
        \end{tabular} 

    \caption{Annahme 2} 
    \label{tab:annahme2} 

\bigskip
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Abkürzung} &\textbf{Bezeichnung}  &   \textbf{Beschreibung} &   \textbf{Quelle}  \\ 
            \hline\hline
        \end{tabular} 

    \caption{Annahme 3} 
    \label{tab:annahme3} 

\bigskip
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Abkürzung} &\textbf{Bezeichnung}  &   \textbf{Beschreibung} &   \textbf{Quelle}  \\ 
            \hline\hline 

        \end{tabular} 

    \caption{Annahme 4} 
    \label{tab:annahme4} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks again david! Your solution worked perfectly!

About the scaling: 
I would also rather not scale, but if I don't do it the table simply continues to the right until its over the page....not sure how to handle this, but with the scaling...any ideas on that?

Comment: Also....I have the 4 columns but the should all have a different width....If I use tabularx and set an (X|X|X|X) they all have the same width....wish is useless to me

Comment: @user1670184 you can do as I did here and  define a table that is no wider than the document, you never need to scale. Obviously if you specify the table is ~24cm wide (as in the question) and the page is not that wide it will overflow. But that is nothing specific to tables, if you specify any box that is wider than the page it will overflow. The tabularx documentation shows you how to vary tabularx columns, or you could use tabulary or (usually better) just specify suitable columns to start with.